# Client Side Datatable is not refreshing after insertion

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, datatable

This is my ajax request code. After adding new record my datatable functions sorting,paging,searching is not working for new record. I guess Datatable is not loading new Record

```
   $.ajax({
    url : 'RoleServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
        action:"get"
    },
    success : function(responseText) {
        $('#role-data-table tbody').empty();

        for(x in responseText){
            $("#role-data").append("<tr><td>"+responseText[x].role+"</td> 
         </tr>");
        }
     $('#role-data-table').DataTable();
    }
});
```

Comment: `type: POST`, `action: get` ehh what? Probably not returning your new record because you're not really inserting anything.

Comment: action:get is for recognizing what action is performed like add update delete get. get is for getting data

Comment: Gotcha.. well without more code it's not possible to say exactly what's wrong